# How to append a long list of static properties to a function in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to type this function that has a long list of static strings appended to it as properties which return the property as a string value:

```js
const arr = ["a", "b", "c"]; // actual list has about 140 items

const f = (tag: string | undefined) => tag;

arr.forEach(key=> {
  f[key] = f(key)
})

console.log(f.a) // "a"
console.log(f.b) // "b"
console.log(f.c) // "c"
console.log(f.d) // undefined
```

Errors:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '(tag: string) => string'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '(tag: string) => string'.
Property 'a' does not exist on type '(tag: string) => string'.
Property 'b' does not exist on type '(tag: string) => string'.
Property 'c' does not exist on type '(tag: string) => string'.
Property 'd' does not exist on type '(tag: string) => string'.
```

[Typescript Playgound](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwTAvDA2gIjpgNDTAIzwOEwF0BuAKGtElgDNUYAKKOAcwC4ZoEAlmE4wAPjACuYACYBTRkNnSAlKgB8MDpxrVECAHSMQCAKJxgAC1YBrWQE8UGgN7UYMRult3yLRjfvK1AC+gXTgECAANrL6kSCcrIz6cIH0EdGx8Yn6hKnhUTFxCUnAeZAFmcX6Kq4wQA)

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you'll need to declare the array of static properties `as const` to make the type `['a', 'b', 'c']` instead of `string[]`.

```
const arr = ["a", "b", "c"] as const;
```

Now get those string constants out as a union of string literals by getting the type of that that array, and then indexing that type by `number`.

```
type Keys = (typeof arr)[number] // "a" | "b" | "c"
```

Then declare the type of the function, and the static properties separately.

```
type TagFn = (tag: string | undefined) => string | undefined
type StaticProps = { [key in Keys]: string }
```

Now you can intersect those types to make the static properties part of the function type.

```
type TagFnWithStatic = TagFn & StaticProps
```

---

Typescript won't like it if you create a function and say it's a `TagFnWithStatic` type without the static properties declared, because those properties must be defined to satisfy the type. To fix that, let's generate the static properties as their own object separately.

```
const staticProps = arr.reduce((result, prop) => {
  result[prop] = prop;
  return result
}, {} as StaticProps)
```

Which can then be merged with the function on assignment to a variable via `Object.assign()`

```
const f: TagFnWithStatic = Object.assign(
  (tag: string | undefined) => tag,
  staticProps
)
```

Now the following should work as you expect:

```
f.a // type: string
f.b // type: string
f.c // type: string

f.d // type error, because static property is not present in `arr`
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)